# Moment js add date and format fails

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to add days to a specific date and format the output. So I have the following:

```js
addDays(date){
    return  moment(date).add(365, 'd').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
}
```

I have tested the above with the following

```js
console.log(addDays("24/05/2021")) //this returns invalid date
console.log(addDays("05/06/2021")) //returns 06/05/2022
```

In the first date it returns `invalid date` and the second one I expected it to return `05/06/2022` but it returns the wrong date.

What am I missing for this to work. My dates are in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: your date you're passing is wonky, see [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Depending on what you expect from adding 365 days, your result may be of by one day in leap years. Ie adding 365 days to 2021-01-01 will be 2022-01-01. But adding 365 days to 2020-01-01 will be 2020-12-31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing because `momentjs` can't parse that date.

You'll have to specify the format your passing:

```js
moment(inputDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

<sup>[MomentJS String + Format documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)</sup>

---

Please see below example which will the expected output:

```js
function addDays(inputDate){
  return moment(inputDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').add(365, 'd').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
}
 
console.log(addDays("24/05/2021"));
console.log(addDays("05/06/2021"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```
24/05/2022
05/06/2022
```

---

That said, I'd still recommend using `moment().add(1, 'year')`:

```js
function addDays(inputDate){
  return moment(inputDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').add(1, 'year').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
}
```

```js
function addDays(inputDate){
  return moment(inputDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').add(1, 'year').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
}
 
console.log(addDays("24/05/2021"));
console.log(addDays("05/06/2021"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks this works.

Answer (score 1):

Does it? If you really want to add a year then `.add(1, 'year')`, not 365 days.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in 2 way:
Using `day` and `year`

```js
let addNYears = function(years = 1, date) {
  return moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').add(years, 'year').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
}

let addNDays = function(days = 1, date) {
  return moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').add(days, 'day').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
}

console.log(addNYears(1, new Date())); // +1 year
// this is not the best way as each 4 years we have a leap year.
console.log(addNDays(365, new Date())); // +365 days
console.log(addNDays(5, new Date())); // +5 days
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```